# Collision between Sprite and Shape Renderer Circles

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Im working on a game where you have to avoid Asteroids with a Spaceship (Sprite).  Unfortunatly my collision method does not work. I can run the Code on my phone but no "Collision" gets printed out. I think somehow i messed up some Coordinate but i cant find the mistake. Any ideas?

```
public class CollisionManager{

private List<Asteroid> asteroids = new ArrayList<Asteroid>();
private Spaceship s = new Spaceship();

public void checkCollisions(){
    for(int i = 0; i < asteroids.size(); i++)
    {
        if(asteroids.get(i).getBounds().contains(s.getBounds())   )                        
        {
        System.out.println("COLLISION");
        }
    } 
}
```

}

Main Class:

```
    [...]
    @Override
    public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen() != null){
        ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen().update();
        ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen().update(renderer);
        ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen().update(cam);
        ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen().checkCollisions();

    }

    if(ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen() != null){
        ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen().render(batch);
        ScreenManager.getCurrentScreen().render(renderer);
    }
}
```

Asteroid:

```
[...]

 public void update(float deltaT) {

    p.x += v.x * deltaT;
    p.y += v.y * deltaT;

} 
     public Circle getBounds()
{
    return new Circle(p.x, p.y, radius);
}
```

Spaceship:

```
[...]
public void update() {

    System.out.println("update");

        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        y =  (height - Gdx.input.getY()) /height *  MyGdxGame.HEIGHT;
        x =   Gdx.input.getX() / width * MyGdxGame.WIDTH; 
        sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth() / 2 + x, sprite.getHeight()/2
         + y);


    }

public Circle getBounds()
 {
    return new Circle(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), sprite.getWidth());
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger to view the values of variables involved in the collision calculation. Alternatively, you can use LibGDX's logging facilities to output these values and view them with logcat.

Comment: That is really ugly indentation, I must admit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use overlap not contains .

```
asteroids.get(i).getBounds().overlaps(s.getBounds())
```

[image]

this means contain. Its not collision check it checks whether or not circle in an other circle completely.

---

[image]

this is what you want.You can check collision with overlap method.